# I'm trying to connect my Baofeng UV-5R to my 888s, UV-5 receives perfectly but can't send to the 888s. I've tried many things with no success :(

Tags: baofeng, uv-5r, chirp

I recently purchased 6 Baofeng UV-5R radios and have been trying to connect them to my 888s radios. I've downloaded Chirp, tried programming the tones into the UV-5 but nothing seems to work. I'm very new to all this but somewhat technically inclined and eager to learn. I would love some help with this and would also be interested in finding a class or mentor that can give me some in-depth education. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Hello Alain, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  You haven't given us very much to work with in your question, I'm afraid.  How did you program the BF-888S radios?  Please edit your question to include a screenshot of CHIRP with the UV-5R settings in it.

Comment: What values has your research indicated the BF-888 uses for the tones?  Also, which channel are you trying to use?  Finally, are you sure that you have the 5r setup for simplex?